# Incorporate symbol in the center of every word

Tags: r

Is there a way to incorporate a symbol in the center of the each letter. Example

```
asd <- c("A","sdf","sfgs")
```

Expected

```
"A + sdf + sfgs"
```

Comment: In case you're making a formula, yout might check `reformulate(asd) # ~A + sdf + sfgs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `paste` with `collapse=` option.

```
paste(asd, collapse=" + ")
# [1] "A + sdf + sfgs"
```